# Referential Integrity issue

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

On my frontend, I have divided the process of asking for User information in 2 steps.

**In step 1**, I am actually collecting "Username", "desired Password", and "Email" which I am storing in a individual table called 'patient_signup'

**In step 2**, I am asking for Firstname, Lastname...
all of such information is being stored in a table called 'user_patient_data'.

Now, what I want to do is, connect both the tables using some common criteria.
The idea of Primary and foreign keys comes to mind but how do I do this?

Should I just copy the Primary key into the "Foreign key"? Is that possible?
If not, what's the other solution for this?

I am including the screengrab of the database structure.

[From Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYLl9.png)

[From Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9btu.png)
Thanks!

Comment: *"The idea of Primary and foreign keys comes to mind"* - That's exactly how to maintain referential integrity in relational databases.  The `user_patient_data` table would have a foreign key to the `patient_signup` table.  So after you insert a `patient_signup` record, you use that record's key to insert a `user_patient_data` record.

Comment: You can probably benefit for a quick lesson of the basics of relational databases. There are many decent online courses you can get or even just tutorials. These are relational database fundamentals which it would be good to learn if you want to make correct use of databases

Comment: Your schema could benefit from a little refinement - do you need a `varchar(128)` for a zip/post code for example? Perhaps `unique` key for email too? etc etc Many of the `enum` could be done again with FK to other tables so that table just stores the key rather than the full text value

Comment: Thank you!
That is the Idea that I had but I am not able to put it in code.

Can I use the following code to do it?
Insert into user_patient_data (patient_id)
select id
from patient_signup

Considering patient_id as my foreign key here in the second table "User patient Data"

Comment: You guys are definitely right, I need some serious training in this regard.
I have never worked with front or backend before. This is my first time practicing of all these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option, and probably best, is to put all the info into one table. You can populate whichever columns at whichever time you want.

To do what you describe however, you would do exactly as you state, so for instance, if the user login data has an `id` column as its primary key, you would put a column like `user_id` in a column in your other table as just a normal indexed column, then you would store the user id integer in both columns in both tables.

Then when you want to pull the data together, you would form your sql using a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

`SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN user_patient_data ON users.id = user_patient_data.user_id`

Then it would pull all fields from each table into a result that you can iterate.

On a side note this question has nothing to do with html or css, so no need for those tags.